# Fill input value inside a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to set the value for each input inside a `v-for`, but the value is not shown in the input.  `{{slideshow.timeout}}` is printing the value, but the `v-model` is not working.
 Am I missing something? I'm new to Vue.

```
<tr v-for="(slideshow, index) in slideshows">             
      <td>{{slideshow.timeout}}</td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" :model="slideshow.timeout" class="form-control">
      </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
  <input type="text" v-model="slideshows[index].timeout" class="form-control">
```

since `v-model` is a directive et it's not a bound attribute